# How to copy from Excel to a Word table retaining the shading of the cells?

Tags: excel, ms-word, copy-paste, shading

I have an Excel model which generates tables where via conditional formatting cells are shaded in particular colors depending on a value. I must copy these tables into a Word doc template and keep the cell shading. The issue is that shading is lost if I copy and paste it into an existing table in the Word document. The only walkaround I have found so far is to split the table in the Word doc, delete the part I need to copy into, and then copy the table from Excel as a new table. In this case, the shading is copied too. The issue with it is that it's an extra step and it messes with formatting. I wonder if there is a way to copy directly and keep the colors.

Probably there's a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you want to copy in Excel and paste them into your Word document by selecting the destination of the cells within your table, clicking on the right mouse button and selecting "Overwrite Cells (O)" under "Paste Options". Normally, your cells should have the same colour as the Excel file.